# linear dependncy of a random vector with respect to a reduced row echelon form in a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, random

Given a matrix with elements from a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, $A\in\mathbb{F}_q^{N\times M}$,
where $q$ is the size of the field, $N<M$. Suppose that $A$ in the reduced row echelon form. Obviously, the rank of such $A$ is $N$.

Suppose that now I generate a $M$-dimensional random vector $\mathbf{f}\in\mathbb{F}^{1\times M}$, with elements uniformly randomly chosen from $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is that possible to exactly compute the probability that $\mathbf{f}$ is linearly independent with those $N$ rows of $A$? I feel like it should be close to $1-\frac{q^N}{q^M}$, but not much sure. If it is not, any clue to look into the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to exactly compute, and we need only classical probability. Your question amounts to choosing an $N$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q^M$ (the row space of your given matrix which you said has rank $N$) and then asking the probability that a randomly chosen vector does not lie in that subspace. Well since the subspace contains $q^N$ elements and the whole space contains $q^M$ elements, and each vector is equally likely to be selected, the probability is 
$$
\frac{q^M -q^N}{q^M} = 1 - \frac{q^N}{q^M}
$$
as you suspect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just have one point not very clear though. Do you mean that any $N$ linearly independent vectors in here would generate an $N$-dimensional subspace of size $q^N$, no matter  of the probability distribution that how elements of these $N$ vectors are chosen? What I mean is, if those $N$ linearly independent vectors consist of elements uniformly randomly chosen from $\mathbb{F}_q$, it is then quite obvious that the probability I needed is $1-\frac{q^N}{q^M}$. But how about those $N$ existing vectors consist of elements not uniformly random from $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: @YeLi The subspace is the space spanned by the rows of the matrix that you said is given, so the subspace is not random. The random process in your question is picking a vector in $\mathbb{F}_q^M$.